# Check if TeX installed is MikTeX

Tags: miktex, emacs

Is there a way to check from command line whether `tex` and other commands belong to MiKTeX or some other distribution (I want to only `(require 'tex-mik)` in Emacs initialization if it's needed)?

Comment: Do you want to check if miktex is installed or if it is the active tex system at the emacs startup? (I have miktex and 3 texlive systems and constantly switch the pathes to use or another).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To check the active system at startup. Out of curiosity, why are you switching? Are you developing packages or styles and testing them for compatibility?

Comment: I'm switching mostly for debugging. If there is an error in one system but not in the other one can search for differences. Also my customers have all sorts of texsystems, so it is good to know something about everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `pdflatex` for that. If you call `pdflatex --version` you get which distribution is used, in my case TeX Live:

> pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)
>
> kpathsea version 6.2.0
>
> Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>
> [...]

Or you can use the `latex` command, which works the same.

Comment: I open my command line and write (tex): I get the message This is Miktex , Version 3.14459 (Miktex 22.7) (preloaded formar=tex.fmt) restricted \write18 enables. Once I insert pdflatex, I get the error 'I cant find pdflatex'